# Empty gaps between data pulled via loop (from multiple Excel files)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
path ="C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\Stock Trackers\\"

excel_file_list = os.listdir(path)


finalDf = pd.DataFrame()
for file in excel_file_list:
 #if excel_files.startswith("Stock"): 
    df = pd.read_excel(path+file,sheet_name="Main",usecols="A:D,R")
    df['Qty Received']=df['Total Received']
    df = df.drop('Total Received', axis=1)
    df['InvoicedValue'] = df['Price']*df['Qty Invoiced']
    df['ReceivedValue'] = df['Price']*df['Qty Received']
    df['DeltaQty']= df['Qty Received']-df['Qty Invoiced']
    df['DeltaValue']= df['ReceivedValue']-df['InvoicedValue']
    finalDf = pd.concat([finalDf, df])


finalDf.to_excel("finalfile4.xlsx")
```

The above script generates the "finalfile4" but the issue is that the final output does not have all the data (for each file) stacked on top of each other.

After each file (so each iteration of the for loop) there are empty rows until row 10982 after which the next file's data starts:

[image].

In between the data of two files you have blank rows except that the "Qty Received" column has zeros.

How can I fix this so each iteration of the loop outputs data right below the previous file's data?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a whole column populated with a formula in your original excel sheets. From your screenshot, it looks like the A (`no name`) and F (`"Qty Received"`) column have values even if the rest of the rows are blank. You could delete these rows from the dataframe you read before you concatenate it to the master dataframe.

```
...
for file in excel_file_list:
 #if excel_files.startswith("Stock"): 
    df = pd.read_excel(path+file,sheet_name="Main",usecols="A:D,R")
    df = df[df["EAN"] != ""] # Select only those rows where EAN is not blank
    ...
```

Comment: Ah yes - you are right! The only issue is that the initial "read_excel" still has to read the formula (which produces the zeros) which takes lots of time even if I apply your suggestion (your suggestion above has been running for 20+ mins even though the total data size is 200 MB and 40 files "only"). 

Is there any way I can amend your code so that before even reading the Excel, it looks at EAN and if it's empty, it drops the whole row? This would make the subsequent read_excel step a lot faster I think?

Comment: I'm not sure how you could tell the cell is empty without reading it. If you can open the file in Excel faster than `pd.read_excel`, it might be a better idea to remove the empty rows using a macro, but that is another question :)